# Prevent API Call During Rails Create in Seeds File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, geokit

I have a rails model that uses geokit that includes the line `acts_as_mappable :auto_geocode=>true` which calls something like `before_validation :geocode_address, :on => :create`. However, my issue is that I have a seeds file for my development database that calls th Rails model and then calls this on create, which calls an external API and fails when I'm not connected to the internet. What approaches are available to me?

It would be nice if the approach covered both this case and when I run my tests as well, but I already have a work around for the tests that isn't very pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
# /db/seeds.rb

ModelName.class_eval { acts_as_mappable(:auto_geocode => false) }

# Create seed models...

ModelName.class_eval { acts_as_mappable(:auto_geocode => true) }
```

This might even work,

```
ModelName.acts_as_mappable(:auto_geocode => false)
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution would be the `skip_callback` method:

```
ModelName.skip_callback(:validation, :before, :auto_geocode_address)
```

Comment: so I would put the first line at the top of my development.rb file and the last line at the bottom if that's what is called when I create the seed models? If so that didn't work. The problem, I believe, is that it hits the Model and is using the default value of true.

Comment: Put those lines of code at the top and bottom of your `seeds.rb` file, around the code that creates the models that you don't want to auto-geocode. I'll add the filename to the top of the code example.

Comment: It's still not working. I'll play around with this general idea.

Comment: Tried calling `acts_as_mappable` on agency like so: `agency.acts_as_mappable(:auto_geocode => false)` where agency is a local variable already setup. I get `undefined method `acts_as_mappable' for #<Agency:0x007ffc5b9a5970>`. I think opening up the class and modifying it is a good approach, not sure how to execute it though.

Comment: Try `Agency.acts_as_mappable(:auto_geocode => false)`. You would need to call `acts_as_mappable` on the model class, not an instance of the model.